# XmlObject.Factory.parse() don't return the type of XML Document

Tags: xmlbeans

I am trying to upgrade XMLBeans version 5.1.0 from version 3.1.0.
The XML Document when running on the application can not parse with **XmlObject.Factory.parse**.

```
XmlObject xmlObj = XmlObject.Factory.parse(content, opts);
```

It worked well with version 3.1.0 before. But after upgrading to 5.1.0 xmlbeans, it always returns XmlAnyTypeImpl type.
Even, it can parse when calling the Inner Factory class directly:

```
Example: SORAccountReadResponseDocument xmlObj = SORAccountReadResponseDocument.Factory.parse(content,opts);
```

Has anyone had the same problem and how to solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: I've changed quite a few things in regards to class loading and metadata location. I could think of several reasons why this happens. I would start with a small project only containing the schema and test Java 8 vs. your current Java version. if this fails, you need to provide the XSD ... as I'm one of the maintainers, I'd encourage you to open a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS)

Comment: Hello guy, I have tested parsing the Document by JunitTest. It worked but when running on the server it can not work. What should I do now? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the reason is that there's a MyDocument.Factory class that would handle the type conversion and a XmlObject.Factory member that only knows anyType. And somehow, even though XmlObject.Factory is package private, my compiler uses that instead of the MyDocument.Factory class methods. We should compare JDK implementations.
PS: calling a member variable Factory with capital F is a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with XmlBeans since version 5, because someone thought, it would be smart to change XmlObject.Factory from an internal class to a member variable by the same name (including capital 'F').

Sadly that breaks overriding (at least for the JDK i'm using, Adoptium JDK 17), because the member variable that returns XmlAnyTypeImpl will be used instead of the internal class of your document, which would return MyDocumentImpl.

And that's exactly what happens, if you keep using your xsd jars that were compiled with XmlBeans 3 and try to run them against XmlBeans 5.

No idea how Apache doesn't have tests to notice this, or maybe they don't think people will keep using their old xsd jars. I'm not sure having internal classes and member variables compete for the same name is even properly defined in the Java spec.

What you need to do is recompile all of your xsds with XmlBeans 5 and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm that someone smart mentioned above. If old user code outside the beans reference the "Factory", it's simplier to ask them to recompile than requiring other code changes. The old inner class Factory was a lot of duplicated code. IIRC having a reference on the class loader was also a design decision to use the new factory classes

Comment: I facing the same issue. Any ides for a solution?